# Angular JS, is it possible to set ng-include or ng-controller dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and through research it looks like this is not possible but I wanted to double-check/see if there is some alternative solution that will have a similar result.

What I want to do is populate a page from a JSON file, and load a customized li using the url that would be on that JSON file. so something like this:

JSON/inside controller:

```
function ExCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.examples = [
            {name:"example", 
            num: 1, 
            url:"website.html"}
        ];
    }
```

JS (inside JS)

```
<ul ng-controller="ExCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="example in examples">
      <div ng-include src="folder/{{example.url}}> </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Solution :

```
<ul ng-controller="ExCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="example in examples">
      <div ng-include src="example.url"> </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

where it is now:

```
function ExCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.examples = [
            {name:"example", 
            num: 1, 
            url:"folder/website.html"}
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the documentation:

> `ngInclude|src` – `{string}` – angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in quotes, e.g. `src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"`.

In your case it makes sense to set a custom ngResource.  In the controller, inject the resource and query for the JSON, then assign the JSON to a scope variable.

```
angular.module("foo", "ngResource")

  .factory("ResourceType", function($resource){
    return $resource("/resourcetype/:id", {id: "@id"}, { "update": {method:"PUT"}});
  })
  .controller("ExCtrl" function($scope, ResourceType){
    $scope.examples = ResourceType.query();  
  });
```

You would then set your ng-include url as you loop over your resource.

Also, don't {{}} your variable name.

EDIT:

I was going to give you a Plunker, but it seems to be acting up.  Here is inline source that does what you would like.  For the sake of clarity, I removed the resource piece.  I imagine you will want to put it back when you decide to retrieve the JSON remotely.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <li ng-repeat="example in examples">
        If {{example.url}} were valid, it would load in the div. 
        <div ng-include="example.url"> </div>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </body>
</html>

var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.examples = [
     {name:"example", 
      num: 1, 
      url:"example.html"}
  ];
});
```

Edit: Plunk

http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/JNhqoJoykWKf4iqV0ieJ?p=preview

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to this and I'm having trouble deciphering what each part of that function is doing or its goal as a whole.. is this a function that sets the url from the controller?

Comment: I updated my question to greater reflect what my current system is, if that helps.. I am able to get it to properly resolve my url now.. it will say ng-include src="example.html" instead of example.url but it hasn't loaded it?

Comment: Thank you, that's much easier for me to follow - however, when I write simply ng-include="example.url" the final result is still ng-include="example.url" :( it doesn't evaluate to anything

Comment: well I just modified yours and it's working on the plunker.. checking my code

Comment: I had my file in a folder so it was really url:"folder/example.html" when I bring it back up to the same folder it works.. is there any way I can have it in the subfolder?

Comment: It's a regular old url. you can make it an absolute URL if you want. That's unrelated to Angular.

Comment: I'm still looking to load the url from JSON data, and having it in the subfolder seems to be breaking it. nginclude="folder/example.url" isn't working

Comment: Okay, I can prefix my data's url (example = [ {name... url:"folder/example.html"..) and it will work, I would really like to not have that prefix have to be in there but it will work like this. Thank you for your patience.